# How to generate Table of Contents on left side of Preview?

Tags: table-of-contents

It's easy to generate a Table of contents inside a LaTeX document using "\tableofcontents", but when opened in Preview on Mac (Preview is an app to view PDF), The left side doesn't show any table of contents. Here is an example of what I want:

[image]

Do you know any package or setting step that can generate this kind of table of contents? Thanks.

Comment: add `\usepackage{hyperref}`

Comment: this must be a duplicate I'll see if I can find a link to close the question

Comment: sure if there is a similar question pls close mine. thanks.